# Convert class to JsonElement (com.google.gson.JsonElement)

Tags: java, json, gson

```
public String toJson() {
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = builder.create();
    return gson.toJson(this);
}
```

This method converts a class into a JSON string. But I want to convert a class into a `JsonElement`. Is this directely possible or do I have to parse the string again?

Comment: Use [`toJsonTree`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.7/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJsonTree-java.lang.Object-) ?

Comment: @JornVernee Thank you! That's the method I was looking for.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `toJsonTree` method of `Gson` class

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(object,typeOfObject);
```

Reference [javadoc](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.1/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJsonTree-java.lang.Object-java.lang.reflect.Type-)